# Xcode bug after crash

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

While I was creating a build to test on my iPhone xcode 8 crashed, when I re-opened xcode  all of a sudden this error came about from no where.

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255. The tool may have crashed. Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com with the above output and attach any crash logs for ibtool, ibtoold, Xcode, and Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool created around the time of this failure. These logs can be found in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports or /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.

Can any one tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you took a look at these crashes ?

Comment: In the DiagnosticReports?

Comment: Yeah, in the given directories. are you able to open xcode again?

Comment: Yes I have, and yes I can open xcode but it throws this error and wont let me create a build.

Comment: Any usefull info there ( perhaps add the logs to question )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I deleted anything related to my project from

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

xCode--> Window--> Projects--> Delete Derived Data.

Closed xCode and open it again.

I hope I help.

[image]